# When did the AWS S3 API’s ListObjectsV2 command come out?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Amazon rarely, if ever, releases API version changes. They prefer to do everything right the first time around. `ListObjectsV2` is a rare exception to this. When did they come out with this new API version?

Not able to find anything out on the docs.

Comment: You'd probably have to ask AWS at this point.  It was [added to botocore in 2016](https://github.com/boto/botocore/commit/fa0a846b27b795089d7bd665fd1b661892d8e761#diff-d7b91deb9b62e50043095232b8cfd5776a40d404b8fa7a3e0a03f0e1b0e499f2R453), but that tends to lag the AWS API by a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Document History - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/WhatsNew.html):

> GET Bucket (List Objects) API revised
> The GET Bucket (List Objects) API has been revised. We recommend that you use the new version, GET Bucket (List Objects) version 2.
> May 4, 2016